# Determining whether the following are functions

Tags: functions

> Which of the following are functions?  If $f$ is not a function, explain why.
> (a) $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 - x^2}$
>  (b) $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ with $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{2}$ 
> (c) $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = \ln x$

So I think all 3 are not functions.

i) is not a function as for -1 and +1 there is no image.

ii) for all odd number the is no image as the domain is a set of integers. We can also say the co-domain does not contain all possible values for the function.

iii) is not a function as for negative values there is no image.

I'm not sure whether my answers are correct. Can someone guide me?

Comment: Your answers are correct

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting a link to an image since images cannot be searched and links can get broken.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you so much. Is my explanation for the part ii)  correct?

Comment: I would personally have given explicit examples for each.  (a): $f(1)$ is undefined (*division by zero*), (b): $f(1)$ is not in the codomain, (c): $f(0)$ is undefined.  With regards to how you wrote your answer to (ii), if I were to read it one sentence at a time... the statement "*as the domain is a set of integers*" by itself is not reason enough to call it not a valid function.  It has to do with the fact that you try to map odd integers to non-integers, which are not a part of the codomain.